# Seaborn Scatterplot ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to do a cluster plot from the t-SNE output using seaborn scatterplot. Below code

```
tsne_cluster = TSNE(perplexity=40, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=2500, random_state=23)
new_values_cluster = tsne_cluster.fit_transform(EMBEDDING_LIST)
sns.scatterplot(new_values_cluster[:,0], new_values_cluster[:,1], hue=y, legend='full', palette=palette)
```

When I run this, I get error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

I checked the length of `new_values_cluster[:,0]` and `new_values_cluster[:,1]` and they both are 200 (same size). So why am I getting this error?

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you checked the `hue=y`?, I am guessing it's will never going to be the same. I'm guessing, that it's will never going to be the same shape as `new_values_cluster`.

Comment: @m-zayan thanks, removing hue=y resolves this issue. If you post it as an answer I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `hue=y`, I guess it's will never be the same shape as `new_values_cluster`.